# Запрос к mysql, где where равно значениям из массива

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток, господа.

Есть массив с циферками ($array_digit), кол-во циферок не известно. Хочется сделать запрос к БД, что-то в роде

```
mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `table` WHERE `field`='???'",$db);
```

И тут возникает вопрос. Как? т.е. В моем случае условие для WHERE сейчас пишу ручками. Да и по 20-ть значений разделенными "OR" тоже не оптимально. Как можно решить данную задачу?

p.s. Очень охота сделать массиву `implode(',',$array_digit);` и как-то с этим уже сделать запрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_query("SELECT `field` FROM `table` WHERE `field` IN (".implode(',',$array_digit).")",$db);
```

Comment: данный вариант будет работать только если поле `field` - цифровое

Comment: попробую применить. спасибо, работает